# Excel pivot table reading from xml

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

Can Excel 2007 use an external xml file as the connection for a pivot table?  I am able to filter the dialog by xml when specifying a type of data however I get an error saying that it is not a valid datasource.

Answer (score 1):

After importing the data to a sheet, you can then create a pivot table using the imported data. You can have a pivot table looking directly to an outside source.